# Why isn't getRange() working within the onChange event after unhiding rows?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to run some script when a user unhides rows. The only way, that I can see, to detect when a user unhides rows is within the onChange event. The only way, that I can see, to try and determine what changed is through the changeType property. However, when a user unhides rows, the changeType is equal to OTHER. OTHER can mean all kinds of things. So I'd like to try and determine if rows were unhidden.

What I noticed is that when I unhide rows, those rows are now selected (have focus). So in theory, I should just be able to use getActiveRange() to return the rows that were just unhidden.

The problem is that when I use getActiveRange within the onChange event, it returns nothing. However, if I call getActiveRange after the onChange event function code has completed, then I get the correct information...even though I have not changed what I have currently selected in the sheet.

Why is getRange() returning nothing while within the onChange event?

The following onChange code will show a dialog box with the number of rows that is returned by the getActiveRange method when the user unhides rows.  The code will add a menu item called Plan -> Test. Clicking Test will show a dialog box with the number of rows currently selected. To try this out, hide some rows, then unhide them. When you unhide them you will see a dialog box that says 0. Then go to Plan -> Test in the menu and you will see another dialog box that indicates the real number of rows that you just unhid.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Plan')
      .addItem('Collapse Section', 'collapseSection')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Test','testThis')
      .addToUi();
}

function testThis() {
  var thisSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var thisRange = thisSheet.getActiveRange();
  popMsg(thisRange.getNumRows());
}

function onChange(e){ 
  var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (e.changeType == "OTHER") {
    // some other event occurred, possible Unhiding Rows    
    if (activeSheet.getName() == "Portfolio") {
      // only execute this code if the OTHER event occurred while on the Portfolio tab
      var thisSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      var thisRange = thisSheet.getActiveRange();
      popMsg(thisRange.getNumRows());
    }
  }
}

function popMsg (thisMsg) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();  
  var thisMsg = ui.alert('Information',thisMsg,ui.ButtonSet.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's an open issue on retrieving the active range within `onChange()` event, check for any update at [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760104).

Comment: Too bad it doesn't seem like this has been addressed over the past 5 years... sigh :(

Comment: Yeah, also P2 is the standard priority level while S2 stands for mayor bugs, which they say that "have a workaround and can be put off without impacting the functionality of the application". :(